# Fen - Check if King is on e1/e8

Tags: castling, fen

Is there some easy way to check whether the black king is on e8 or the white king is on e1, when using fen?

> Here the black and white king are on d1/8 `r2k3r/3q4/8/8/8/8/8/R1QK2RR`
>
> Here both are on the right field `r3k2r/3q4/8/8/8/8/8/R1Q1K1RR`

The problem is that there is really no regularity, to check by indexing whether the King is on e1/e8.

> The fen above, could also be `rb2k2r/3q4/8/8/8/8/8/R1Q1K1RR` and would still be valid.

Checking for the rocks are pretty easy, since they have to be at the beginning or the end of the fen.

Comment: Sure, "are there exactly four spaces accounted for before the K". What is the context here? Are you writing code, or what?

Comment: Yeah I am writing code. `4K3` is also valid and there are not 4 spaces.

Comment: Sure there are; I carefully did not say "four characters". You just have to treat numerals and alphabetical characters differently.

Comment: If you're writing code, then I suppose this is a question for stackoverflow.com

Comment: Also, a full [FEN record](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forsyth%E2%80%93Edwards_Notation) includes castling availability information, which appears to be what you're actually looking for in the first place. After all, the *current* placement of Kings and Rooks is not sufficient for determining if a player can castle.

Comment: @HenryKeiter I am aware of that, but I wanna let the user create a position and set whether white/black is allowed to castle or not. Afterwards I wanna check if the rocks and the king are in the right position for that.

Comment: Not very difficult to code this yourself. You're really looking for the last row, so 1) get the last index of / . 2) get the remaining substring (e.g. R1Q1K1RR). 3. Check if this string contains K. 4) Iterate over this substring - count = 0; foreach(character in string) { if (c == 'K') { count = count + 1; break;  } else { if (c is number) { count = count + number} else { count = count + 1 } } Now, if count is 5, then the king is on e1.

Comment: To add to Henry's answer this is the proper nomenclature in a FEN file for castling availability: If neither side can castle, this is "-". Otherwise, this has one or more letters: "K" (White can castle kingside), "Q" (White can castle queenside), "k" (Black can castle kingside), and/or "q" (Black can castle queenside).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to Henry for the tip. Here is my solution.

```
var kingOnRightField = function (groundRow, king) {
    var index = 0;

    for (var i = 0; i < groundRow.length; i++) {
        var number = parseInt(groundRow[i]);
        index += isNaN(number) ? 1 : number;

        if (index == 5 && groundRow[i] == king) return true;
    }

    return false;
};

var fen = "r3k2r/3q4/8/8/8/8/8/R1Q1K1RR";

var blackGroundRow = fen.split("/")[0];
var whiteGroundRow = fen.split("/")[7];

var blackKingOnRightField = kingOnRightField(blackGroundRow, 'k');
var whiteKingOnRightField = kingOnRightField(whiteGroundRow, 'K');
```

Comment: Have you tested the code with different types of FEN?

Comment: Yup I did. I updated my post as I wrote a handy function.